# I'm precaching pictures for UIView animation array using graphic image context. How can I free memory in case I need this array no longer?

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-management, uiviewanimation

I'm precaching pictures for `UIView` animation array using graphic image context.

How can I free memory in case I need this array and all those images no longer? Is `_pictureArray = nil` enough?

```
- (NSMutableArray *)generateCachedImageArrayWithFilename:(NSString *)filename extension:(NSString *)extension andImageCount:(int)count
{
    _imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _fileExtension = extension;
    _imageName = filename;
    _imageCount = count;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        NSString *tempImageNames = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i", filename, i];
        NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:tempImageNames ofType:extension];

        UIImage *frameImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frameImage.size);
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, frameImage.size.width, frameImage.size.height);
        [frameImage drawInRect:rect];
        UIImage *renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        [_imagesArray addObject:renderedImage];

        if (_isDoublingFrames)
        {
            [_imagesArray addObject:renderedImage];
        }
        else if (_isTripplingFrames)
        {
            [_imagesArray addObject:renderedImage];
            [_imagesArray addObject:renderedImage];
        }

        NSLog(@"filename = %@", filename);
    }

    return _imagesArray;
}
```

Comment: Assigning array to nil will not release memory allocated to array, you need to release memory allocated to array.You can return [_imagesArray autorelease]; and retain wherever you are using this array. And once you are done with array you can release it.

Comment: @NuzhatZari I'm under ARC so autorelease doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the image you want to free from the array
or call `removeAllObjects` on the array to clear it

as the array is the only one holding the images (assuming you dont show it right now)

---

- freeing items from the array can be done using `removeObject` or `removeAllObjects`
- freeing the array can be done by :

  - (non-arc) calling `release` or
  - (with arc) setting it to nil (but thats not reliable.) So i'd call `removeAllObjects'